# Passing Base64 Bytes to AWS Rekognition Compare faces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

As mentioned I am trying to pass Base64 encoded Images to the AWS API for comparing faces. But its giving me error :

```
An error occurred (InvalidImageFormatException) when calling the CompareFaces operation: Request has invalid image format: InvalidImageFormatException
```

I tried earlier using S3 bucket images and it worked properly. But right now I am trying to send the images without using S3 bucket.

I am using a Lambda function, and I referred to [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/faces-comparefaces.html)

My code (edited version) :

```
source_image_string = "/9j/4......." //Base64 stringified image
target_image_string = "/9j/4A......" //Base64 stringified image
source_byte = base64.b64encode( bytes(source_image_string, "utf-8") )
target_byte = base64.b64encode( bytes(target_image_string, "utf-8") )

response=rekognition.compare_faces(SimilarityThreshold=70,SourceImage={'Bytes': source_byte},TargetImage={'Bytes': target_byte})
```

And the error that I am getting in the Cloudwatch is :

```
An error occurred (InvalidImageFormatException) when calling the CompareFaces operation: Request has invalid image format: InvalidImageFormatException
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 113, in lambda_handler
raise e
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 105, in lambda_handler
response = compare_faces(source_image_string,target_image_string)
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 43, in compare_faces
response=rekognition.compare_faces(SimilarityThreshold=70,SourceImage={'Bytes': source_byte},TargetImage={'Bytes': target_byte})
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Where am I going wrong?, as the `source_byte` that I am passing is of the `Byte` format.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to encode the base64 string (from a video frame):

`buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
image_data = base64.b64encode(buffer)`

And then pass the Bytes as:

```
Image={'Bytes': image_data}
```

and it works fine.

It seems like you already had the b64 string in x_image_string, I think that's what's giving you trouble with the format .

Comment: Hi Hugo, Is this a comment or a full answer? Can you make that clear on the answer itself?